# Get methods and comments from a ruby file + YARD

Tags: ruby, yard

Ok I have task where I have to extract methods and comments from ruby file and store them in db as reference

before this I manage to spin off with this piece of Code to achieve the same

```
module Describe
  def describe(method_name,description)
    @@method_descriptions ||= []
    @@method_descriptions << [method_name,description]
  end

  def method_descriptions
    Hash[@@method_descriptions]
  end
end
```

and then use something like this inside  a class

```
   class A
      extend Describe

      def call_me
      end
      describe :call_me,"This method is you to invoke"
   end
```

But the Fact that I have to write the some code to this is and also they aren't the actual comment

Can I achieve the same thing with YARD

Answer (score 0):

YARD uses an enhanced notation of RDoc, so at least you can write the documentation as comments above a method.

The raw output data from YARD can be stored in a database. At least, that is what the [Feature list](https://github.com/lsegal/yard#feature-list) claims.

Comment: I know that YARD extract comment out also I dont need to add documentation to the file using YARD all I need is to read the Comment mention inside the file and stored them in DB